# The conclusions taken by James about the Blair Witch

Tags: plot-explanation, blair-witch-2016

In the end of *Blair Witch*, James concludes that

> She only takes sacrifices. We can't look directly at her.

What does the 'sacrifices' part mean? How does the Blair Witch only take sacrifices, and how is that related with looking at her?